# How to alter value returned from mock to one passed in earlier to a different mock

Tags: c#, moq

I'm having some trouble putting this into words, but the gist of it is that I'm mocking a data source (an Aerospike client in this case) in order to test some merging logic in the parent code. So I'd like to test a sequence of writing and reading data. Therefore, I'd like for data passed into the function `.PutMap` to subsequently be returned when the function `.ReadMap` is executed.

I'm also retrieving the model that is passed in in a callback so I can check it against expected values.

The following test code is what I've tried. It is NOT working.

```
var mockAerospikeClient = new Mock<IAerospikeClient<AerospikeConfig>>();
// If a model is pushed to Aerospike, copy that model so we can check it against expected
ExampleModel modelPutInAerospike = null;
mockAerospikeClient
     .Setup(x => x.PutMap(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ExampleModel>(), It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
     .Callback<string, string, ExampleModel, int?, CancellationToken>((s1, s2, model, i, _) => modelPutInAerospike = model);

// Mock returns model that was put in earlier
mockAerospikeClient
     .Setup(x => x.ReadFromMap<ExampleModel>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
     .Returns(Task.FromResult(modelPutInAerospike));
```

It seems like the `.Setup` functions reads `modelPutInAerospike` immediately, and I'd really like something like a pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

So, in typical fashion, I tried something new while writing the question that worked.

The answer was to perform the `.Setup` for `.ReadFromMap` in the same callback as where I'm retrieving the model. It is totally possible to have a callback execute multiple statements.

Example:

```
var mockAerospikeClient = new Mock<IAerospikeClient<AerospikeConfig>>();
// If a model is pushed to Aerospike, copy that model so we can check it against expected
ExampleModel modelPutInAerospike = null;
mockAerospikeClient
    .Setup(x => x.PutMap(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ExampleModel>(), It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .Callback<string, string, ExampleModel, int?, CancellationToken>((s1, s2, model, i, _) =>
    {
        modelPutInAerospike = model;
        // Mock returns model that was put in earlier
        mockAerospikeClient.Setup(x => x.ReadFromMap<ExampleModel(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(modelPutInAerospike));
    });
```

Notice the use of brackets `.Callback(() => { statement1; statement2; });`.